# Show block if user has never completed Ubercart checkout

Tags: 7, ubercart, blocks

Part of my website's signup process is the purchase of a product via Ubercart. The signup process directs the user to the checkout page with the product already in their cart. The problem I am having is when users get to the cart and then abandon their cart.

I'd like to add a block to the user profile pages that says "Your profile is not yet complete. Please click here to enter your payment info", and I only want that block to show up for users who have not completed that order process. How can I filter users in that way to make that block show up only for those select users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it figured out, at least for my own use-case:

1. I use a webform to collect info on the newly-signed-up user. That webform then redirects to the checkout page with the product in the cart. I used the Webform Rules module to auto-assign a "pre-customer" role to the user when they finalize the webform. Then, when they complete the cart checkout process, that user role is removed and the "customer" user role is assigned to their account.
2. I've got a block that is visible only to users with the role "pre-customer". That block is the one where they will be prompted to click a link to finalize their order/payment info.

Hope this can help someone else at some point! :)

Comment: That's indeed a way to answer your own question (which you should mark as accepted ...)!